# Swift - SpriteKit - distance between a moving node and a fixed node

Tags: sprite-kit, swift4

I want to set the width of a node to be the distance between a moving node and a fixed node. In other words, I hope that the width of the node changes as another node moving. Is there a function to do this ?

Comment: What have you researched?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `hypot` function:

let distance = hypot(movingNode.position.x - fixedNode.Position.x,
                         movingNode.position.y - fixedNode.Position.y)

This returns the length of the hypotenuse of a right-angle triangle of width x and height y, which we can envisage as being drawn with your two nodes being on the non-right angled vertices.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1456251-hypot

[image]